# How do I remove the post format meta box?

Tags: post-formats

Is it possible to remove the "Post Format" meta box from the edit/new post page?
The blog in question has a lot of users that keep messing with that but it only uses the standard format post.

I'm kind of new to wordpress so excuse me if this is a really obvious one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That gets added because your theme supports `post-formats`.

You can either use a plugin (or a child theme's `functions.php`) file to hook into `after_setup_theme` late and remove theme support:

```
<?php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpse65653_remove_formats', 100);
function wpse65653_remove_formats()
{
   remove_theme_support('post-formats');
}
```

Or look for the the line in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_theme_support('post-formats');
```

and remove it.

The first option is a better bet.  Stick it in a plugin and it will be there for the next theme you use as well.

Comment: That was thorough. Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Higher value on the priority then the default of 10 makes sure this is run after the initial removal.
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_post_format', 15);
function remove_post_format() {
    remove_theme_support('post-formats');
}
```

This should be placed in your functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and best way to do that is typing in your functions.php the function below:

```
<?php remove_theme_support( $feature ); ?>
```

$feature (string) (required) - Name for the feature being removed.

Features list:

'post-formats'
'post-thumbnails'
'custom-background'
'custom-header'
'automatic-feed-links'
'html5'
'title-tag'
'menus'

For example, if you want to remove the post-formats you can type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_post_format'); 

function remove_post_format() {
    remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted because there are already two answers to this question providing this solution.

Comment: Downvoted? I was just trying to help. This way is better stop helping. Don't worry, I'm deleting it and stopping helping.

Comment: I'm sorry that I came across as dismissive. Maybe I am missing something, but to me this answer seemed to be essentially the same as the two answers that already existed. One way of helping others find the right answer can be to upvote an existing answer, rather than adding another answer that basically provides the same solution. Please do not stop trying to help; I was actually trying to help as well, help you learn how to use the site, but I admit I did a poor job of it! I hope it will not turn you off from continuing to try and provide answers for people.